# Regex: <word> <capture group> <specific words but in any order> <capture group> in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

The code snippet below works, but I don't like the `(?:terminate.*instance|instance.*terminate)` part in the regexp, because it looks like code duplication. It becomes especially ugly when in the middle we can have 3 or more specific required words, but in any order.

Is it possible to avoid the code repetition? Any help is appreciated.

```py
regex = "^ec2 (?P<environment>\S+) (?:terminate.*instance|instance.*terminate) (?P<instance_id>i\-\S+) (?P<reason>.*)"

commands_positive = [
    "ec2 production instance terminate i-ab87cd98bfg this is the reason"
    "ec2 development terminate instance i-abcd12bcdg reason"
    ]

commands_negative = [
    "ec2 production instance falsecommand i-ab767cdc reason",
    "ec2 testing instance terminate i-abcdfgg",
    "ec2 development terminate instance i-abcd8733"
    ]

    for command in commands_positive:
        self.assertRegexpMatches(command, regex)

    for command in commands_negative:
        self.assertNotRegexpMatches(command, regex)
```

Comment: is it possible to have the text `terminate terminate` and you don't want to match? if not this regex would work: `(?:instance\s*?|terminate\s*?){2}`

Comment: @Koala I don't want to match for `terminate terminate`. So the only acceptable words are: `instance terminate` and `terminate instance`. I can't accept `instance instance` or `terminate termintate`.

Answer (score 0):

Go with `lookahead` if you want to match words in any order:

```
(?=.*instance)(?=.*terminate).*
```

This will match everything except the string

```
ec2 production instance falsecommand i-ab767cdc reason
```

Lessens your dups

Comment: I need to capture things too not only match. I wish I only need to match..

Comment: huh...it captures the whole string, albeit with a performance hit when you read the whole string trice